# How to show notification in front rather than on statusbar with notification icon when app is in foreground?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code is as shown below:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderHistory.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ORDER_ID, notificationMap.get(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ORDER_ID));
        intent.putExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ORDER_STATUS,
                notificationMap.get(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ORDER_STATUS));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("QuFlip")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now, whenever the notification comes,it shows android bydefault app icon in statusbar. But what I want to do is, I want to show proper notification, just like when the app is not running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1347/notifications/6379/heads-up-notification-with-ticker-for-older-devices#t=201704111731180003099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setLargeIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
If it's won't help, try to add:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Set the PRIORITY_HIGH and DEFAULT_SOUND flags:

```
        notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        notification.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

It also works if you set DEFAULT_VIBRATE but that's more intrusive.